While trying to send keys in Selenium Web Driver IDE I am getting "Value Required"
I am using Selenium web driver IDE to automate the user journey of my application. Which include filling out a form. Although I am able to select the same element using the locator when I am inspecting through the "Developer Tool". But in IDE i am getting an error.
I checked my element only difference I found was "automcomplete" for the for is give "off". Due to constraint I am posting a mobile capture of the error. Could some help. Let me know if you need more information as I could not find similar post.
Error on my browser(IDE):

WebDriver Steps :


I am able to fixed this issue.
RC: This is happening due to the event dispatcher, so after entering the keys, which is the value, the event was not dispatching from the current field while the tool has already reached the next element.
How I fixed it ?
I added one more step after the value entered,
Command: execute script

Target: var input = document.querySelector('#name'); input.value = 'jyotiprakashltd'; input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
Value:

